# C# Is there an easier way to create a database, empty tables, tables with data in them by default, stored procs and views?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Before I posted this question, I did some Googling first on how a database was created through C# and mostly it points to either SMO or SQL query files and it was the time of SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

So at this day in age, is there an easier way to create a database with empty tables, tables with data in them by default, stored procedures and views?

I need a suggestion.

Comment: Entity Framework's code first?

Comment: "Easier" than what, exactly?  There isn't anything out there which will somehow be able to automatically generate your entire custom structure and logic.

Comment: guess code first is applicable, because can modify database schema by code. Database first can't.

Comment: Why are you using C# to create a database?   Why not use SSMS?

Comment: @Frisbee My "server" app creates store branches with their own databases. So my "server" app needs to create a database for a new store/branch created.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Frisbee So what if I handle 100 stores and they each add 1 branch I would have to manually add the branch databases?

Comment: If it's all copies of the same initial database, you could create it once, create a full backup file (.bak) and simply restore it with different database names or on different servers (very simple c# and sql code). if every customer needs his own structure and logic, then I don't know of any "easy" was to do it using c#.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is probably Entity Framework.  You can do 'code first' and use database migrations, allowing you to write your C# code and use that to generate a lot of the database for you.

Ultimately though, 'easier' is subjective.  I personally find EF great for the 'normal' stuff, but at the end of the day, if you need a stored procedure to do some custom logic; you need to write the custom logic, in some fashion.

Maybe have a look and see if you think it fits your needs.

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Is it also applicable in Database first? or just code fist?

Answer (score 0):

Looked at the database projects in studio 2013. You create a database as a series of scripts using a familiar GUI. However, changes are published - this process creates a unique change script targeting the connection you define. For new databases the whole thing gets created, but publish against a partial or out dated version and the script created in a change script to bring it up to date.

You can even writ unit tests against your database using specialist tools, although I do find them lacking a bit.

More on msdn - [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xee70aty(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Depends.  right out of gates. Sp and views. Best shot is directly from database through a workbench.  I can then capture definitions and store in a file to be replayed through c#

As for tables  there are many orms that can generate tables via c#.  Look at entity frameworks.  Code first examples

I have generated tables using EF   Works fine. I then went into database and created views and sps.

The trick is to migrate new views and sps into your EF model U can google entity  Frameworks code first ... Adding views and SPs.

Worst case is u create database all through database workbench. Create a script that an be played to recreate eveything. By running.  Then use EF DATABASE first approach

In either case u end up with a good set of autogenerated code to manage CRUD and object management and an abstracted data model

Comment: Is it also applicable in Database first? or just code fist?

Comment: I am a database guy.  So for me. I typicAlly use database first   Because my solutions end up needing sps.  Doing database first  I don't have to mess with anything other then updating my EF model in a few clicks.  My database outlive the application   Vs. the app being the centerpiece

Comment: Sorry, missed the line where you said "then use EF DATABASE first approach" I will try to look more into that.

Comment: U can use code first.  Then u have to use migrations because u are managing your db mostly through EF.   I did db first against an existing db and had data importing to insert rows from a workbook in less then a day. It saves a ton of time.